# Preventing Interface Distortion and Scaling Issues in Remote Desktop Sessions

Tags: remote-desktop

When using RDP to access a remote computer, some applications' interfaces become distorted and extremely small, negatively impacting the user experience. Furthermore, each time I connect, the remote computer's resolution seems to change temporarily – the interface first becomes smaller and then returns to its original size, even though both computers have the same resolution and the specified remote resolution is the same. This issue persists even when using both the UWP version of Remote Desktop and the built-in Remote Desktop Connection, both set to the same resolution as the remote computer (2560x1440).

Here is my RDP file listed below:

```
screen mode id:i:1
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:2560
desktopheight:i:1440
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,3,0,0,800,600
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:6
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:103.91.211.138:35823
audiomode:i:2
redirectprinters:i:0
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectwebauthn:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
drivestoredirect:s:
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:0
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
enablerdsaadauth:i:0
```

Comment: Which RD apps are you using? The Remote Desktop Connection is different from the Remote Control Viewer, and what you're describing is the RCV behavior, not the RDC behavior. So please confirm the app/service you're using for RD and the settings you are using for it.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks. I just want to clarify, when you mentioned "Remote Desktop Connection," are you talking about the built-in Win32 version within the system, and is "Remote Control Viewer" the UWP version found in the Microsoft Store? I have experience with both versions. I've updated the problem description with my RDP file details.